# Flutter/Firestore - not displaying newly added/changed data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter and trying to use it with a Firestore database. What I'm trying to do is, setting up a stream to read documents from a certain collection, which I then display within a list. This displays a few values, which are correct. But when I add or change data within the firebase console, these changes aren't displayed in my app.

My code:

```
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  String url;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chats').snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case null:
                  return Container();
                default:
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final item = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                      final itemID = snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID;
                      final list = snapshot.data.documents;
                      print(item['senderName']);

                      return Dismissible(
                        key: Key(itemID),
                        background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(item['senderName']),
                                onTap: () {
                                  print(itemID);
                                  url = item['senderName'];
                                  _sendDataToSecondScreen(context);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // get the text in the TextField and start the Second Screen
  void _sendDataToSecondScreen(BuildContext context) {
    String textToSend = url;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
            text: textToSend,
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Example:
I initially got 3 documents in my collection, each containing a value "senderName". All of them are displaying correctly within my app. When I go into Firebase console and manually add a 4th document, also containing a value "senderName", this is not being displayed within my app. I tried closing everything and restarting, but nothing changes.

I'd be really happy if anyone's got an idea on what I'm doing wrong here.

UPDATE - [Data structure in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DBnW.png)

Comment: Could you share the structure of your data in firestore? And you want the app to get updated or when you reload to see the new documents?

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot from my firestore database. Is this what you meant? Ideally data should update automatically, but right now it's not even updating when I reload the page.

Comment: I guess the screen shot you shared also has 4 documents in chat section! correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you're absolutely right, my fault! I've got 4 documents and only three of them are being displayed. I corrected the example above.